# JPanel wont scroll within JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've looked at many examples that are suppose to make a JPanel be able to scroll within a JScrollPane, but none of the implementations worked in my case. My JPanel is larger than the JScrollPane, but when I run it, the scrollbars doesn't reflect to the size of the JPanel accordingly.

```
        ePanel = new EnvironmentPanel(); // class that extends JPanel

        environmentSP = new JScrollPane(ePanel.getPanel());
        environmentSP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1235, 780));
        environmentSP.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        environmentSP.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        environmentSP.setViewportView(ePanel.getPanel());

        this.frame.getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.frame.getContentPane().add(environmentSP, BorderLayout.EAST);

        splitPane.setRightComponent(environmentSP);
```

Comment: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For instance, we have no idea what the preferred size of the `ePanel.getPanel()` is. I'm not sure why you try to add it **twice** to your JScrollPane either. That's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

We can't answer your question without guessing because you've not posted a [minimal runnable example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I'll guess anyway. My guess is that this assumption:

> My JPanel is larger than the JScrollPane

is in fact false. Find out yourself -- debug your code and have it print out the sizes of the constituent components including the JPanel held by the JScrollPane, `ePanel.getPanel()`, and the JScrollPane itself **after the components have been rendered** of course, and you'll see.

For instance, something I've done is to place a println statement in a paintComponent override, something like:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       System.out.printf("Panel Size: [%d, %d]%n", getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

And this will tell you **exactly** what your component's size is **when it is being rendered**. Do this before your `setPreferredSize(...)` fix, and you'll see that sometimes the best way to debug is to throw all assumptions out and instead test to see what is in fact happening in running code.